# Android ViewFlipper with 2 views

Tags: android, events, view, switch-statement, swipe

I'm looking for help with creating ViewFlipper which will work like in android calendar when switching between months by swipe.

I want to have only two views inside my viewFlipper, and when i swipe right i want to do

```
mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild( 1 );
```

and when i swipe left :

```
mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild( 0 );
```

and when i swipe twice left, i want to get every time full in/out animation and the same for right swipping. Full animation works only when i swipe to next and to previous, never in direction of next -> next.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're *only using 2 views*, and at present and you're setting 0 and 1 manually as such, just call

```
mViewFlipper.showNext();
```

instead regardless of the swipe direction and apply the correct animation depending on if you want it to be sliding left or right. This will mean even if you're on view 1 and you slide right again (like you defined) then view 0 will come back in, like a never ending flipper between the 2 views.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html

I may be totally misunderstanding your question however, it is rather vague.

Answer (score 1):

See this link it may help.....

http://www.1mobile.com/effective-navigation-863044.html

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**folder in res = animator.......

translation animation xml file = s_in_fleft  in animator folder in res folder.....
might help**

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();

        if (lastX < currentX) {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                break;

            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.animator.s_in_fleft);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.animator.s_out_right);
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }

        if (lastX > currentX) {
            if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                break;

            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.animator.s_in_fright);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.animator.s_out_left);
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```